# I'd like to know which one is 'the main verb' in the given sentence

Tags: verbs

> One fine summer morning at the beginning of harvest, in 1771, I think it was, Mr Earnshaw, the old master, came downstairs, dressed for a journey.

Comment: I would suggest *came*.

Comment: Stripped of adverbial clauses, the sentence is "Mr Earnshaw came downstairs".  The main verb is "came", therefore.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Surgery, while at times necessary, never leaves things looking very nice :(

Comment: @chasly from UK Just to 'in 1771', surely. The actual year would be more fugitive than the details of the occasion.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - You are right. I was so focussed on pointing out that it didn't refer to the subsequent clause that I became careless about what it did refer to. I'll resubmit the comment.

Comment: Note that, the adverbial clause "I think it was", refers to, "in 1771". It does not refer to "Mr Earnshaw".

Answer (score 1):

The main verb is come. The other verbs are part of circumstancial clauses.

Comment: No, it doesnt differ, that was a mistake on my part. Fixed it.